# nextjs app:Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80

Tags: node.js, next.js

I have err when i run nextjs app on port 80.

here is my package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 80",
}
```

here is err when i run yarn dev

```
error - Failed to start server
Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:80
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1415:21)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1480:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1568:7)
    at D:\MCP\monorepo\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:144:16
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.startServer (D:\MCP\monorepo\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\start-server.js:129:11)
    at setupFork (D:\MCP\monorepo\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:337:65)
    at runDevServer (D:\MCP\monorepo\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:348:23)
    at async nextDev (D:\MCP\monorepo\node_modules\next\dist\cli\next-dev.js:457:9) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: -4092,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '0.0.0.0',
  port: 80
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

my nodejs version:v16.17.0

my computer specification:

```
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎4/‎22/‎2021
OS build    19045.2846
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4190.0
```

anyone can give me solution to run app without change port.Thank alot

Answer (score 1):

Port numbers below 1024 are privileged ports (In this case, 80 < 1024). You have to run your command using Administrator privilege (Windows) / `sudo` (Unix) or change to another port (Recommended to change port).

If you understand the risk and are using WSL here, you can try to run it using `sudo yarn dev`

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. But do you have another solution to use that port without WSL and change the port?

Comment: Try to run your terminal with Administrator privilege (eg. Right-click on your Command Prompt / Powershell, and click on "Run as Administrator")

Comment: I did that. but it not work